# What does it mean to set the technology matrix of the Leontif Input Output Model to 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, economics

I'm just beginning to learn about Leontif Input Output Systems and Linear Algebra. 
What is the significance of the solution if I set the technology matrix equal to the trivial solution (make the system of equations into a homogeneous linear system)
$$ \left[
   \begin{array}{ccc|c}
   \frac {-1}2 & \frac 13 & \frac 12 & 0 \\
   \frac 14 & \frac{-2}3 & \frac14 & 0 \\
   \frac 14 & \frac 13 & \frac{-3}4 & 0
   \end{array}
\right] $$
This is assuming that the original system is: 
$$\frac 12x + \frac 13y + \frac 13 z = x$$
$$\frac 14x + \frac 13y + \frac 14 z = y$$
$$\frac 14x + \frac 13y + \frac 14 z = z$$
Where $x, y, z$ are the production values of the three sectors of a simple economy. Amount supplied is equal to the amount demanded.

Comment: From the beginning it is a homogeneous linear system, because you have no constant. You just summarize the x´s, y´s and z´s. Now you can apply the methods for solving homogeneous linear systems.

Comment: I know how to solve it but I'm not sure what is the significance of the answer. Conclusions like, Ie: (what does it tell you about the economy? is it the optimal amount produced?) etc. I don't know if this makes sense.

Comment: The solution tells you what amount of x,y and z you have to produce, if you have no net output. The trivial solution is $x=y=z=0$ The general solution is $(x,y,z)=(x,\frac{3}{5}x,\frac{3}{5}x)$. This is the solution of the first equation system. There is a typo in the first line (z).

Comment: To answer you question: No it doesn´t make sense. If it is a company you want to sell something. In this case you can´t sell something, because you have a net output of zero. If it is a country you have no consumption and no investions. Thus it wouldn´t make no sense, too.